# Is there a way to use Specifications in ElasticsearchRepository?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I've implemented the Specification pattern for filtering some of my JpaRepositories. After I have implemented a Specification, I can use it with a JpaRepository like this:
`Page<Entity> page = entityJpaRepository.findAll(entitySpecification, pageable)`

Is there a feature, or planned feature, for supporting Specifications in ElasticsearchRepository?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your pain however the thing is that `Specification` interface belongs to the **JPA** API that currently none of the Elastic Search Spring Data repositories implement and I don't think they will.

If you really want to use them you should rather migrate from ElasticsearchRepository coming from spring-data-elasticsearch into JPA-based repositories.

Did not try to use **JPA** together with ElasticSearch myself but noticed that some people does it, check out this link:

https://programmertoday.com/spring-boot-elastic-search-with-spring-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `Specification`s, but Spring provides a bean `ElasticsearchOperations` which has a "search" method which accepts `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.CriteriaQuery` which is similar to standard hibernate `Criteria`. Try mapping `Specification` to `CriteriaQuery`.

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooService {

  private final ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate; // autowired bean

  public void search() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.and(new Criteria("foo").is(foo));
    criteria.and(new Criteria("bar").in(bars));
    CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(criteria);
    elasticsearchOperations.search(criteriaQuery, 
        FooElasticEntity.class).stream()
           .map(SearchHit::getContent)
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
  }
}
```

Also it's worth to note that there is a `SearchHitSupport` utility class which adds support for `Pageable`.